# Format POSIX scenario in Dates

Tags: r

Create a variable of value 15Aug1947 and 15Aug2018 in POSIX Date format.
Find the number of days elapsed since Independence as of 15th August 2018.

Need to code in R language.

```
DATE1 <- c("15Aug1947")
DATE2 <- c("15Aug2018")
X <- as.Date(DATE1, "%d/%m/%y") - as.Date(DATE2 , "%d/%m/%y")
print(X)
```

Comment: Please provide your code and explain what is not working. See best practice for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: DATE1 <- c("15Aug1947")
DATE2 <- c("15Aug2018")
X <- as.Date(DATE1, "%d/%m/%y") - as.Date(DATE2 , "%d/%m/%y")
print(X)

Comment: This looks like a homework question. SO inhabitants are more than happy to help, but we usually need some proof that you've tried to solve your problem on your own first. If you are not willing to invest that time, perhaps seeking a professional to do this a fee would be a better venue. Not sure which venue would that be, though.

Comment: I tried this but not executing according to the problem given @AlbertoDallaporta

Comment: DATE1 <- c("15Aug1947")
DATE2 <- c("15Aug2018")
X <- as.Date(DATE1, "%d/%m/%y") - as.Date(DATE2 , "%d/%m/%y")
print(X)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am not getting the correct output as well. Please help me in this.

Comment: PLease help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information. Comments aren't perfectly suited for sharing code.

Comment: sure doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You are close, but are missing a small detail. The second argument in `as.Date` requires you to specify *exactly* in what format your dates is coming from. Right now, you are saying your date is comprised of 15/08/1947. Two things are wrong with this. Your date has no slashes and the month is not an integer but an abbreviation of the month name. The correct way to parse this date would be

```
> ps <- "%d%b%Y"
> DATE1 <- c("15Aug1947") 
> DATE2 <- c("15Aug2018") 
> X <- as.Date(DATE1, ps) - as.Date(DATE2 , ps) 
> 
> print(X)
Time difference of -25933 days
```

For more information on how to construct the string for parsing, see `?strptime`.

You can use a package to parse dates automatically, such as [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The following code may help!

```
#Create a variable of value 15Aug1947 and 15Aug2018 in POSIX Date format
dt <- c(as.POSIXct("15Aug1947", format = "%d%b%Y"),as.POSIXct("15Aug1948", format = "%d%b%Y"))
#Finding the number of days elapsed
difftime(dt[2], dt[1], units = "days")

#Time difference of 25933 days
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may help, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable for the StackOverflow community

Comment: ```as.numeric(difftime(dt[2], dt[1], units = "days"))``` will remove all text messages